# Alias Directive for shared hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, alias

How would I indicate Alias directives on shared hosting.

The file I want to serve is located:

home/user/public_html/the_file_I_want_to_serve.html

I would like to serve the file described above in:

home/user/desired_folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/HERE

I read the [Apache's documentation on Alias directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html), but I am unsure if I place directives in public_html/.htaccess or in desired_folder/.htaccess

Then I wonder, would directives in htaccess recognize a folder outside of its domain?

the url to load home/user/desired_folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/HERE is a subdomain like temp.domain.com which points to home/user/desired_folder/subfolder1/subfolder2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Alias` directive is not allowed outside of the server/vhost config. Since the htaccess file is a "per directory" context, there's no way to do anything outside of the context of the document root. Which means you can't do/know anything outside of the root (which I'm assuming is `/home/user/public_html/`. You'd have to move the "desired_folder" into the public_html directory, or at least symlink it from the public_html directory.